# Rails: Using migrations to create an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a `User` table and a `Product` table. There is a `has_many :products` and a `belongs_to :user` relationship. I defined the Product and User models correctly...my question is about setting up the migration so that the schema comes out right. I tried and this was the extra line in the schema that i got.

`add_index "product", ["user_id"], name: "index_product_on_user_id"`

I then had a look online and instead of add_index other code had add_reference...does that matter? And not sure about the name: "index_product_on_user_id". Thanks!

Comment: I guess it should be products instead of product `add_index "products"`

Comment: `add_index :products, :user_id`

Comment: There will be multiple same `user_id` in products table. Why you want to index on `user_id` instead you should index on product `id`.

Answer (score 2):

`add_reference` adds the required columns and (optionally) creates an index whereas `add_index` just creates the index, so if you want to use `add_index` you need to create the column separately.

You almost never need to set the index name - it doesn't affect how the index works or is used (one case is where the autogenerated index name exceeds the maximum index length).